# HL7 clinical orders and response messages

Tags: hl7, medical, hl7-v2

We have a scenario to **create orders from our system for clinician’s service** in HIS, like Clinician Orders for (*Requesting clinician/doctor/nurse for some service like Bed Check, Patient Review etc..*).

Searched internet to find some ORM-ORU samples to get an idea but was unlucky.

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone provide **samples of ORM order Hl7 messages and its corresponding results (ORU R01) for this scenario**.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://www.pacsgroup.org.uk/forum/messages/2/HL7_ORM_and_ORU_agreement-79057.pdf) for ORM-ORU agreement applied in PACSgroup.
Just go through that link and I hope you will get some required info.